# A bank has an unlimited supply of 3-peso and 5-peso notes task?

Tags: ruby, math

**I'm working on an assignment that goes like this:**

A bank has an unlimited supply of 3-peso and 5-peso notes. Show that with these two types of notes the bank can pay any number of pesos greater than 7.

**The answer is:**

The bank can pay 8 pesos by paying one 3-peso note and one 5-peso note.

The bank can pay 9 pesos by paying three 3-peso notes.

The bank can pay 10 pesos by paying two 5-peso notes.

The bank can pay 11 or more pesos by paying 3-peso notes until there are only 8, 9, or 10 pesos left to pay out, and then using one of the above strategies. (If you subtract off threes from a number 11 or larger, you'll eventually arrive at one of 8, 9, or 10.)

**And I'm trying to implement this functionality in a `Ruby` program.**

So far I've done the following:

```
class Money

  def initialize(price)
    @price = price.to_i
    validate(@price)
  end


  def validate(price)
    if price >= 8
      calculate(price)
    elsif price < 8
      puts "Minimum ammount is 8 pesos"
    end
  end


  def calculate(price)
    if price%5 === 0
      fives  = price/5
      threes = 0
    end

    result(fives, threes)
  end


  def result(fives, threes)
    puts "#{fives} five peso notes, #{threes} three peso notes."
  end

end


m = Money.new(ARGV.first)
```

Can you please help me put this maths task in the programm? Thank you.

Comment: You've mostly got it,  although I'm betting that triple equal === was meant to be a double ==

Comment: Think about `r = price % 3`. There are three possible values for the remainder `r`: 0, 1, or 2. Zero means you know a solution already. You just need to come up with a way to write code that handles 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count(price)
  t = 0
  if price >= 11
    t = (price - 8) / 3
    price -= t * 3
  end
  if price == 8
    [t + 1, 1]
  elsif price == 9
    [t + 3, 0]
  elsif price == 10
    [t, 2]
  else
    fail "price too small"
  end
end

threes, fives = count(42)
puts "#{fives} five peso notes, #{threes} three peso notes."
```